# Angular 2 RC1 Router doesn't work without any routerLInk

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

i have serious problem with angular 2 (RC1) router.

This code works:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/anythingEvenNotExistingRoute']"></a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This doesn't:

```
//<a [routerLink]="['/anything']"></a>  <-- without this line in html template
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

...so it looks like angular router needs atleast one routerLink in html template.. thats pretty strange..

Comment: i made a research and router outlet works only if there is next to him any component with reference Router

Answer (score 3):

This is currently a bug present in the Angular 2 RC Router https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8409.

As mentioned in the GitHub issue, to get around it you can either inject the router into `AppComponent` or just put an empty router link (`<a [routerLink]="['/']"></a>`) into your template.

Comment: ... or inject the `Router` to `AppComponent`

Comment: hello.. yeah.. or inject Router  to  other component that is in the View next to the router outlet.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yup absolutely. Updated the answer.